# CSS Section Automatically Adjust Height?

Tags: css, html

I have a HTML section "all" that wraps around two other sections. I'm having trouble getting the website to adjust the height of the "all" section based on the length of stuff I put into the other two sections.

```
<section id="all">
   <section id="left_content">
      <p>Something here.</p>            
   </section>
   <section id="right_content">
      <p>Something here.</p>
   </section>
</section>
```

I currently have the height set at a fixed size of 700px. I was wondering if it was possible in the CSS, to have that section's height be related to the size of the left_content and right_content sections.

```
#all {
    width: 900px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}

#left_content {
    float: left;
    width: 570px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#right_content {
    border-left:4px solid #cccccc;
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0px 10px 20px 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Set #all height to auto. And overflow:hidden;

Comment: I tried this and yes it does what I was looking for. I apologize for not mentioning this but the left_content and right_content will not have the same height so the solutions below resulted in a large gap. This solution takes the larger of the two heights and fills in the #all background correctly.

Answer (score 7):

- Don't give `#all` a height
- Clear your floats

Your wrapper cannot determine a height while child items are floating. You need an element that "ends" the floating. `<div style='clear:both'></div>` is a common way to clear floats. [Clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) is another technique.

Read more: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the height declaration for #all (like Diodeus said). You will then need to apply either a clearing element below the two content divs (like a footer), or apply a clearfix to the div #all.

For instance:

```
/* For modern browsers */
#all:before,
#all:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

#all:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
#all {
    zoom:1;
}
```

This is a direct copy & paste of [Nicolas Gallagher's excellent micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).